# How to add badge to action bar menu item by titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I want to add a badge to android action bar menu item by titanium appcelerator
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of digging and searching i have finally found the answer.

All you need to put badge is [actionView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.MenuItem-property-actionView)

Comment: Do you have an example how to to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Titanium module which bases on this https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge